# How to make dockerfile and .conf file are not accessible direct through url

Tags: docker, docker-compose, dockerfile, configuration-files, httpd.conf

> How to make dockerfile and .conf file are not accessible direct
>   through url

Look this url

- http://localhost/dockerfile
- http://localhost/nginx.conf

If I Open this url this files are downloadable which should be not. How can i prevent this?

Answer (score 0):

You can use a `.dockerignore` file to avoid sending files to your container. [See docs here](https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/builder/) for things like your Dockerfile.

To exclude config files and others that you need in your container from being served, you would do this via your web server config. E.g., for nginx:

```
location ~ (\.conf$|Dockerfile) {
    return 403;
}
```

As a best practice, you might want to structure your project so the Dockerfile root isn't the same as your web root, similar as to how would (should) structure a non-Dockerized app.